# Recursive function that returns a count of elements with the specified value in a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I am working on a function, countH(), that is supposed to count the amount of times a given number appears in a linked list. For some reason, I cannot get this to work recursively. I have tried a number of different solutions but I guess I can't get something in the correct place. Sorry if I am asking the question poorly, I struggle to understand recursion formatting sometimes.

Here is the function:

```
    public int count(int i) {
        return countH(first, i);
    }
    
    private int countH(Node front, int i) {  // TODO
        int cter = 0;
        if (front.next==null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(front.item == i)
            cter++;
        return countH(front, cter);
        
    }
```

This is a late version of my code, I'm sure it was a bit better before I messed with it a bunch to try to get it to work

Thanks!

Comment: What's a `Node`? More of a hint, what is `i`?

Comment: Why? It's an iterative problem. Don't use recursion just to iterate.

Comment: @clwhisk The answer to the question of what is a node lies in classic terms of the computer science, take a look at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 2):

Every recursive implementation consists of **two parts**:

- **base case** - that represents a simple edge-case for which the outcome is known in advance. For this task, the *base case* is a situation the given `Node` is `null`. Think about it this way: if a head-node is not initialed it will be `null` and that is the simplest edge-case that your method must be able to handle. And return value for the base case is `0`.
- **recursive case** - a part of a solution where recursive calls a made and where the main logic resides. In the *recursive case*, you need to check the value of a current node. If it matches the target value, then the result returned by the method will be `1 + countH(cur.next, i)`, otherwise it will be a result of the subsequent recursive call `countH(cur.next, i)`.

**Base case** is always placed at the beginning of the method, followed by a **recursive case**.

And when you are writing a *recursive part*, one of the most important things that you have to keep in mind is which **parameters** change from one recursive call to another, and which remains the same. In this case, changes only a `Node`, the target value `i` remains the same.

```
    public int count(int i) {
        return countH(first, i);
    }
```

```
    private int countH(Node cur, int i) { // `front` replaced by `cur`
        if (cur == null) { // not cur.next == null (it'll fail with exception if the head-node is null)
            return 0;
        }
//        int cter = 0; // this intermediate variable isn't needed, it could be incremted by 1 at most during the method execution
//        if(cur.item == i) 
//            cter++;
//        return countH(cur, cter); // this line contains a mistake - variable `i` has to be passed as a parameter and `cter` must be added to the result returned by a recursive call

        return cur.item == i ? 1 + countH(cur.next, i) : countH(cur.next, i);
    }
```

**Suggestion**

Follow the comments in the code. I've left your original lines in place so that will be easier to compare solutions. Also, always try to come up will *reasonable self-explanatory names* for *variables* (as well as *methods*, *classes*, etc). For that reason, I renamed the parameter `front` to `cur` (*short for current*), because it's meant to represent *any node*, not first or any other particular node.

**Side note**

This statement is called a **ternary operator** or [**inline if statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/IRWUG/ch21s03s01s02.html)

```
cur.item == i ? 1 + countH(cur.next, i) : countH(cur.next, i);
```

And it's just a shorter syntax for the code below:

```
if (cur.item == i) {
    return 1 + countH(cur.next, i);
} else {
    return countH(cur.next, i);
}
```

You could use either of these constructs in your code. The difference is only in syntax, both will get executed in precisely the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In a linked list, you should have one element and from that you get the value and the next element. So your item could look like (I am omitting getters, setters and exception handling):

```
class Item {
    Object value;
    Item next;
}
```

Then your counter for a specific value could look like

```
int count(Object valueToCount, Item list) {

    int result = 0;

    if (valueToCount.equals(list.value)) {
        result++; // count this value
    }

    if (value.next != null) {
        result += count(valueToCount, value.next) // add the count from remainder of the list
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `In a linked list, you should have one element` - no, a list could be *empty*, that doesn't contradict the concept of this data structure. `exception handling` - there's no code that can raise an exception neither in the question no in your answer, what are you going to handle?

Comment: I was thinking of NullPointerExceptions, which would be raised if you do not even have the one element - funnily just the case you made. I acknowledge you caught that one nicely in your solution.

Comment: A simple condition eliminates NPE. And you should **never handle runtime exceptions** with the `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int count(int i) {
        return countH(first, i);
    }
    
    private int countH(Node front, int i) {  // TODO
        if(front==null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (front.item == i) {
            return 1 + countH(front.next, i);
        } else {
            return countH(front.next, i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).